# ow to remove ctp file extension from cakephp view

Tags: php, cakephp

How to remove ctp file extension from cakephp view. What can I do. If it is possible please help me.

Answer (score 2):

**you should try this in your App controller**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $ext = '.php';
}
```

**make a .php file in your View and your controller**

```
public function index() {
     $this->layout="admin_layout";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public $ext = '.php';
```

Add this code in app controller file.

Through this code you can use php extension in the view.